# Cold air blowing from return air vent

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, cooling

Cooling stopped working on my second floor zone, and cold air was blowing out of return air vent.

I turned off the power to HVAC , it didn't work.

When I turned off the thermostat of my second floor zone and turned it on after an hour, to my surprise the issue was gone,
cooling started working in my second zone.

I am really curious to know how  turning off the thermostat fixed the issue.

Hopefully these images helps to understand the issue

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a zoned system (IE: one heat pump or A/C unit), or 2 units, each with their own air handler and HP or A/C outdoor unit???  We need to know more about your system config to help. If two independent systems, I'd guess a frozen evaporator in your AH.

Comment: Was the air handler on full and blowing out the return? Do you think the air handler was running in reverse? Or was the air handler motor stopped and air just leaking out the return vent?

Comment: I think @George Anderson is on the right path a evaporator that freezes can thaw if it happens again make sure your filters are clean if they are your system may be low on refrigerant.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson    It's zoned system. HVAC is on attic , system was on and it was cooling attic too.